# WordPress WooCommerce: Adjust free trial length with coupon?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I'm setting up a subscription website using WooCommerce.  I need to be able to adjust the free trial period based on the coupon code supplied at checkout.  It doesn't appear that this capability is available by default, but I'm hoping that I can achieve this with some custom code.

Does anyone have any pointers on how I might go about doing this?  Is there a WooCommerce hook I can use to easily build this functionality?  I really appreciate whatever help is provided!

Comment: A free trial of what? Are you using the [WooCommerce Subscriptions](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) plugin? I can only suspect that you will need to look through the source code and/or docs to find the action hooks for when a coupon is redeemed in WooCommerce. Next you'll need to locate the code that establishes the trial period in the plugin. With those two pieces, you should be able to build your own addon to extend the trial period.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not providing enough info...I'm using the subscriptions plugin and the free trial is for membership to the site's premium content.

Comment: I suggest you vote this up as a feature here: http://ideas.woothemes.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/4284917-coupons-for-subscriptions-with-a-free-trial

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this using my ["Free trial coupon for woocommerce subscriptions" plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-subscription-trial-coupon/) to extend Free Trial in coupon code. It will work if you use the Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin.

Comment: It appears you may be associated with the plugin which you have linked. If you link to something with which you have association/affiliation, you *must disclose that affiliation in your post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. Please see: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).